# What is the meaning of "life of the collar"?

Tags: dialogue, servant

From *Servant* S01E09: Timestamp 04:20

> Julian : What is the meaning of your son's name ?
>
> Dorothy : It does not mean anything. It's just a great name.
>
> Julian : I think you may have condemned your son to the life of the collar?

What does this phrase mean? What is "life of the collar"?

Comment: It's like saying "man of the cloth". Just an expression meaning "Priest" or similar.  It's old-fashioned.

Comment: ...just don't make a habit of it.

Comment: @Criggie - I got baptised in Times New Roman because the vicar used the wrong font.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The line preceding this statement is

> *"Why Jericho? What does it mean? Biblically speaking?"*

The implication is that by giving the child such an ostentatiously Christian name, they're making it all but certain that he'll end up taking holy orders and start wearing a [clerical collar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_collar)

[image]

---

The expression "*a life of the collar*" itself has been in common usage for some considerable time. For example;

> Marcus Goulding, who is in his seventh year at the seminary and due to
> be ordained a deacon on September 10, believes the church needs good
> priests more than ever. Now aged 25, he got the marks to study law,
> but the calling from God was louder. As he prepares for **a life of the
> collar** rather than the wig, he feels a responsibility for restoring
> the integrity of the church.
>
> <sub><sup>[Daily Telegraph AU- Why young people are lining up to become priests and nuns](https://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/lifestyle/stellar/why-young-people-are-lining-up-to-become-priests-and-nuns/news-story/a8df640b603c7502bff12c8438fa1bc9)</sup></sub>

Comment: This might be a linguistic difference, as I'm not an English native, but to me, a priest's _collar_ refers to [the larger, frilly article of clothing displayed here](https://www.sokelys.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Ragnar-Andersen.jpg). Regardless, this does not affect the validity of the answer. Priesthood is indeed often referred to this way.

Comment: @Arthur No, a priest's collar is the thin white collar next to their skin (which can also be seen on the picture you posted).  Ceremonial collars exist, sure, but the regular priest's collar is normally worn every day as a sign of devotion.

Comment: And "the wig" refers to the traditional white wig worn by lawyers in court.

Comment: @Barmar - In the 21st Century '*perukes*' are only worn by barristers and judges - https://people.howstuffworks.com/culture-traditions/national-traditions/why-british-lawyers-barristers-wear-wigs.htm

Comment: @Valorum Aren't barristers the lawyers who argue cases in court? I'm not that familiar with the British legal system.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes. Unlike the US system where the advocate is also the person that receives instruction from the client, in the UK system a 'Solicitor' is the ones who speaks to the client and receive instructions from them. The [Barrister](https://www.brightknowledge.org/law/what-is-the-difference-between-a-barrister-and-solicitor#:~:text=of%20the%20court.-,Barrister,-Barristers%20can%20be) is the one that actually does the speaking in court.

Comment: @Valorum In any case, I think the metaphor "life of the wig" is not meant to imply that they would specifically be a barrister, it presumably refers to the legal profession in general.

Comment: @Barmar wigs are worn by barristers. Here in the states only bald, vain lawyers wear wigs. ;)

Comment: I agree 100%, @Valorum, that "a life of the collar" is an old phrase, but your supporting quote would do well to have a date without forcing all of us to click through the link to see when that article was written. TBH, there's nothing "old" feeling about the writing in the quote - it could have come from last week. (And now that curiosity got the best of me, that's from 2016, so I wouldn't think that a "considerable time" ago...) :D

Comment: @FreeMan They didn't say it was archaic. It has been in use for some time, and is still in use.

Comment: hi @Arthur - you're completely wrong. A priest's collar is the "thing white thing".

Comment: In the UK, I don't know about elsewhere, many people, including a lot of priests, refer informally to that thing in the picture as a 'dog-collar'.

Comment: @Arthur the larger item is not typically worn by priests in Anglophone nations, so when we say priest's collar we mean the thin white bit you can see next to the skin. I'd refer to the larger item as a ruff (although that term is more typically used to discuss the historical item, common in the Elizabethan era, where the Scandinavian liturgical item likely originates)